# PHP domain name verify

Tags: php, dns

This is an another topic about domain name verify. I read answers in other topics. I tried several scripts. I **don't** want to use an **API**. Unless there is a free API but I not yet found one.

I tried to check the DNS following code:

```
if($_POST['submit']){

    if(!empty($_POST['check_site'])){
        $url = $_POST['check_site'];

        //add .nl
        if(!strpos($url,'.nl')){
            $url.= '.nl';
        }

        //check dns record
        $result  = dns_get_record($url);

        if(count($result) > 0)
        {
            echo $url. ' is used';
        }else{
            echo $url. ' is free';
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to check "example.nl" (A registred but inactive domain) it don't give DNS data back so I validate is as free domain.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone a fix?
2. Does anyone have a suggestion (link to other script/article)
3. Is there a way to check if a site have a **registrar**.

I'm still a student but this is not a school project.

Live code on : [link](http://jdkmedia.nl/PHP)

**I am checking the answers, thanks in advance**

Edit:

When I try to

```
   shell_exec (whois -h whois.domain-registry.nl 'is example.nl');
```

I get a unexpected T_String error. What is the correct way to use this?

Comment: echo $url before dns_get_record() and check what does it contains?

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary the domain name I filled in. You can see it now in the link I added. If the domain name does not contain '.nl' I add it.

Comment: I know but to be sure do check it what does it contains

Comment: I have filed the data with my doamin name and it added .nl is this and also replied me that this domain is registered

Comment: I see @RohitKumarChoudhary but it only need to check .nl domain names.

Comment: Ok then ask your user to put only name he wish, and add .nl in your script. As your code is working . check by putting on test in input . test.nl is already a registered site

Comment: Or you can use regex to validate the input that it should only contains .nl

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. But the problem is more that it valids and inactive domain that is registred as unregistred

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27076/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-choudhary-and-jochemtheschoolkid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PHP functions checks if site is assigned to an IP address or not. That is why inactive domains are identified as free!

Anyway you can check your code again with [checkdnsrr()](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn42re805.html) of PHP.

If it does not works, **there is an [extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/files/phpwhois/) for this purpose. I think it is free**.

Comment: I found it once earlier. I am gonna try it again it gave me a lot errors in localhost (I use that because my site error reporting is off)

Answer (score 4):

If your PHP installation has rights to execute the whois command line utility commonly found on UNIX-based server, you could get your information from the following command:

```
whois -h whois.domain-registry.nl 'is example.nl'
```

This command is taken from [this SIDN page](https://www.sidn.nl/over-nl/whois/domeinnaamgegevens-zoeken/), under 'Is'. You must check whether you can do this more than 15 times a day from one IP address, because you also can't do that for the more complete whois (without 'is'). You also seem to be restricted to one request per second.